# Is it possible to create a custom form field filter?

Tags: joomla2.5

It seems like it should be easy, but I cannot figure out how to filter a text box so that a user can input an iframe, but no other html. I basically want safehtml, but allowing the use of the iframe tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple validation override.

In your form model (the class that extends JModelAdmin)

you can override the validate method:

```
public function validate($form, $data, $group = null) {
    // your validation rule 
    parent::validate($form, $data, $group);
}
```